# How to set object field with thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My Student class has list 'Objects'.

```
public class Student {
    private List<Objects> list;
    ...
}

public class Objects {
    private long id;
    private String context;
    ...
}
```

```
    @GetMapping("signup")
    public String showSignUpForm(Model model) {
        List<Objects> objectsList = new ArrayList<>();
        objectsList.add(new Objects(1, "Math"));
        objectsList.add(new Objects(2, "Phys"));
        objectsList.add(new Objects(3, "Chem"));
        objectsList.add(new Objects(4, "Geom"));

        model.addAttribute("objects", objectsList);
        model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
        return "add-student";
    }

    @PostMapping("add")
    public String addStudent(Student student, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "add-student";
        }
        return "redirect:list";
    }
```

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/students/add}" th:object="${student}" method="post">
   <div class="group">
      <div th:each="obj : ${objects}">
         <input id="check" type="checkbox" th:field="*{list}" th:value="${obj}"/>
         <label for="check" th:text="${obj.getContext()}"></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

So I want to add selected objects to student.list but I get this error:

Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'list'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'example.Objects' for property 'list[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

How to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to work with list you have to do it by index. So if you want to bind a list you have to do like below.

```
  @GetMapping("signup")
    public String showSignUpForm(Model model) {
        List<Objects> objectsList = new ArrayList<>();
        objectsList.add(new Objects(1, "Math"));
        objectsList.add(new Objects(2, "Phys"));
        objectsList.add(new Objects(3, "Chem"));
        objectsList.add(new Objects(4, "Geom"));

        List<Objects> emptyList = new ArrayList<>();
        Student student = new Student();
        student.addList(emptyList);
        model.addAttribute("objects", objectsList);
        model.addAttribute("student", student);
        return "add-student";
    }
```

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/students/add}" th:object="${student}" method="post">
   <div class="group">
      <div th:each="obj,iterator : ${objects}">
         <input id="check" type="text" th:field="*{list[${iterator.index}].id}" th:value="${obj.id}"/>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{list[${iterator.index}].context}" th:value="${obj.context}"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Secondly, if you want to do select and add then you have to use javascript. You have to track the index of the list and bind the value separately (id and context) in the correct index. You have to also consider to remove object from the list for unselection.

Comment: I've used the same but it is not working. Are you sure it is working?